# python-2.7: doctests ignored in setter method of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, setter, doctest

Why does the following example fail to run its doctest in the *setter* method?

```
class Foo:
    a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        pass

    @a.setter
    def a(self, v):
        '''
        >>> 1 == 1
        False
        '''
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The debugger confirms that no test is run (example above written to `dtest.py`):

```
>>> import dtest, doctest
>>> doctest.testmod(dtest)
TestResults(failed=0, attempted=0)
```

The same test in the *getter* method is correctly executed, reporting failure of course...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@a.setter` decorator ignores the docstring and it is not copied to the resulting `property` object; set the docstring on the *getter* instead.

See the [`property` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> If given, doc will be the docstring of the property attribute. Otherwise, the property **will copy fget‘s docstring** (if it exists).

Emphasis mine.

Your code results in:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     a = None
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...         pass
...     @a.setter
...     def a(self, v):
...         '''
...         >>> 1 == 1
...         False
...         '''
...         pass
...
>>> Foo.a
<property object at 0x101a21050>
>>> Foo.a.__doc__ is None
True
```

Set the docstring on the *getter* however and you get:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     a = None
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...         '''
...         >>> 1 == 1
...         False
...         '''
...         pass
...     @a.setter
...     def a(self, v):
...         pass
... 
>>> Foo.a
<property object at 0x101a210a8>
>>> Foo.a.__doc__
'\n        >>> 1 == 1\n        False\n        '
```

Another, ugly workaround would be to recreate the property with the docstring being copied from the setter, explicitly:

```
class Foo:
    a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        pass

    @a.setter
    def a(self, v):
        '''
        >>> 1 == 1
        False
        '''
        pass

    a = property(a.fget, a.fset, doc=a.fset.__doc__)
```

Comment: I see. For completeness sake, could you please add any reference explaining the rationale, proper usage, etc.? The [official documentation] (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/doctest.html) doesn't provide more information.

Comment: @sphakka: it does, actually; I quoted the relevant part.